Blazor: Create root path with parameter
New blazor dev here ✌️
I am trying to build a simple profile page on the root of my domain. Something similar to instagram.com/nike but mydomain.com/nike
I have a default blazor project after running dotnet new blazor with small modifications. I removed default counter and home pages and removed navbar item. Only have few files.
The Index.razor
@page "/{Username}"

<h1>@Username</h1>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string? Username { get; set; }
}

The Index.razor.css
h1 {
    color: red;
}

My problem is that when I have this setup, the css in the whole project breaks...
If I change my path to something like
@page "user/{Username}"

Everything works perfectly. So I guess it's something with project not being able to build properly. Any ideas?
Project setup:

Console errors:


Not sure if you're looking for an optional parameter or not, but you can pass a string parameter to the Blazor component this way:
@page "/"
@page "/{Username:alpha}"

This will allow the user component to render or a user component with a string parameter of 'Username'
@code{
    [Parameter]
    public string Username { get; set; }
}



That I know but I want to achieve this on the root path, not sub path like "user/{username}" but "/{username}"

Check my edit, its exactly the same

what the hell, it seems to work.. Thanks! Is it something special with "alpha"? If I change it to anything else like "beta" or "test", if crashes but it seem to work only with "alpha"

alpha is believe is for alphanumeric. Which is weird, you'd think you'd use {Username:string} but that doesn't work. I tried.

exactly.. It worked for me with :int but not :string. Soooo weird. Thank you again, 6h wasted on this..

If you wish to direct both paths, 'domain.com/' and 'domain.com/nike,' to your page, you can utilize the following code:
@page "/{user?}"

@code
{
    [Parameter]
    public string? User { get; set; }
}

The '?' symbol in {user?} denotes that the value can be nullable."
Since the default type of URL parameters is string, you don't need to explicitly specify the type.
Route constraints

Your page has to be something like: @page "/user/{Username}"
